# How to create multiple sub-accounts under a single organization in demo site under single organization

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

i want to create multiple accounts in a single organization in DocuSign Dev environment. It is a demo site . I want to add multiple account like hr , finance . But all should come under a single organization

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [create the accounts](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/?ga=2.70927056.1363819232.1590515244-192278368.1546193875&ECID=20890&elqCampaignId=20890&LS=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&utm_campaign=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&Channel=DDCUS000016968056&cName=DocuSign.com&postActivateUrl=https://developers.docusign.com/) independently.
You need to [create an organization](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=rrf1583359212854&topicId=oum1583359129731.html&_LANG=enus) for your account.
Then, you can [link them together](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=rrf1583359212854&topicId=mtc1583359175678.html&_LANG=enus) if you're an organization admin for the one account.

Comment: Thank you  , Thanks for the quick response